# Index Error with python code and numpy matrix using spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, economics

> code used error in indexing

```
import numpy as np 
def generate_y(phi,sigma,y_,T,epsilon):
```

> Generates  math:`y_t` following
>
> :math:`y_t = \phi_0+\phi_1y_{t-1}+\phi_2 y_{t-2} + \sigma \epsilon_t`
>
> Inputs
>        -----------
>   * phi (list or array) : [phi_0,phi_1,phi_2]
>
> - sigma (float) : :math:`\sigma`
> - y_ (list or array) : :math:`[y_{-1},y_{-2}]`
> - T (int) : number of periods to simulate
> - epsilon (length T+1 numpy array) :     >:math:`[\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_T]`

```
 Returns
 -----------
 * y(length T+1 numpy array) : :math:`[y_0,y_1,...,y_T]`

 ret = np.ones(T+1)
 ret[0] = phi[0]+(phi[1]*y_[0])+(phi[2]*y_[1])+(sigma*epsilon[0])
 ret[1] = phi[0]+(phi[1]*ret[0])+(phi[2]*y_[0])+(sigma*epsilon[1])
 for i in range(2,T+1):
     ret[i] = phi[0]+(phi[1]*ret[i-1])+(phi[2]*ret[i-2])+(sigma*epsilon[i])
 return ret

def generate_N_y(phi,sigma,y_,N,T):
'''r
 Generates N realizations of y^i_t following 

     :math:`y^i_t = \phi_0+\phi_1y^i_{t-1}+\phi_2 y^i_{t-2} + \sigma   \epsilon^i_t`

 Inputs
 -----------
 * phi (list or array) : [phi_0,phi_1,phi_2]

 * sigma (float) : :math:`\sigma`

 * y_ (list or array) : :math:`[y_{-1},y_{-2}]`

 * N (int) : number of simulations

 * T (int) : number of periods to simulate


 Returns
 -----------
 * y(Nx(T+1) numpy array) : y[i,t] is the realization of y at time t for simulation i
 '''

Tlist = []
for i in range(0,N+1):
    epsilon = np.ones(T+1)
for j in range (0,T+1):
    epsilon[j] = np.random.randn()
    temp = generate_y(phi, sigma, y_, T, epsilon)
    Tlist.append(temp)
    ret = np.vstack(Tlist)
    return ret

def generate_AC(phi,sigma):
 r'''
 Create A,C for the process

 :math:`x_{t} = A x_{t-1} + C\epsilon_{t}`

 Inputs
 -----------
 * phi (list or array) : [phi_0,phi_1,phi_2]

 * sigma (float) : :math:`\sigma`


 Returns
 -----------
 * A ( :math:`(3\times 3)` array)
 * C (length 3 array)
 '''

 A = np.array([[phi[1],phi[2],phi[0]],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
 C = np.array([1,0,0])

 return A,C

def generate_x(A,C,x_,T,epsilon):
 r'''
 Generates :math:`x_t` following 

     :math:`x_{t} = A x_{t-1} + C\epsilon_{t}`


 Inputs
 -----------
 * A (:math:`m\times m` array)

 * C (length m array)

 * x_ (length m array) : :math:`x_{-1}`

 * T (int) : number of periods to simulate

 * epsilon (length T+1 numpy array) : :math:`[\epsilon_0,\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_T]`


 Returns
 -----------
 * x(length :math:`m\times(T+1) numpy array) : x[:,t] is the array :math:`x_t`
 '''
 stack = [1]

 stack[0] = A.dot(x_)+(C*epsilon[0])
 for i in range(1,T+1):
    stack.append(A.dot(stack[i-1])+(C*epsilon[i]))
    ret = np.vstack(stack)
    ret = ret.T
 return ret


def generate_xhat(A,xhat_,T):
 r'''
 Generates :math:`\hat x_t` following 

     :math:`\hat x_{t} = A \hat x_{t-1}`


 Inputs
 -----------
 * A (:math:`m\times m` array)

 * xhat_ (length m array) : :math:`\hat x_{-1}`

 * T (int) : number of periods to simulate


 Returns
 -----------
 * xhat(length :math:`m\times(T+1) numpy array) : xhat[:,t] is the array 
 :math:`\hat x_t`
 '''

 stack = [1]
 stack[0]=A.dot(xhat_)
 for i in range(1,T+1):
  stack.append(A.dot(stack[i-1]))
 ret = np.vstack(stack)
 ret = ret.T
 return ret
```

> RAN in

```
import numpy as np
import HW1_1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
'''
Parameters
'''
phi_0,phi_1,phi_2 = 1.,0.95,-0.5
sigma = 1
y_ = np.array([0.,0.])
T=50

phi = np.array([phi_0,phi_1,phi_2])
```

> Part 1. b.

```
y = HW1_1.generate_N_y(phi,sigma,y_,10,T)
 plt.figure(1)
for i in range(0,10):
 plt.plot(y[i,:])



##############
# Part 1. d. #
##############
x_ = np.hstack([y_,1.])
T=50
epsilon = np.ones(T+1)
for i in range(0,T):
   epsilon[i] = np.random.randn()
A,C = HW1_1.generate_AC(phi,sigma)

y = HW1_1.generate_y(phi,sigma,y_,T,epsilon)
x = HW1_1.generate_x(A,C,x_,T,epsilon)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(y)
plt.plot(x[0,:])
print(y==x[0,:])




##############
# Part 1. e. #
##############
##############
y = HW1_1.generate_N_y(phi,sigma,y_,500,T)
A,C = HW1_1.generate_AC(phi,sigma)
xhat = HW1_1.generate_xhat(A,x_,T)
ybar = np.mean(y,axis=0)
plt.figure(3)
plt.plot(ybar)
plt.plot(xhat[0,:])
xbar = np.mean(xhat,axis=0)



phi_0,phi_1,phi_2 = 1.,0.95,-0.5
sigma = 1
y_ = np.array([0.,0.])
```

> any help would be awesome!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You've added essential parts of your code, but try to explain what you're trying to do also. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Comment: on line 1 of the 4th part of code i get the error :                       plt.plot(y[i,:])

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1